# min(a + b,c) $\leq$ min(a,c) + min(b,c)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the following always true ?  if we have min(a + b,c) $\leq$ min(a,c) + min(b,c) according to the cases I have analyzed it seems to be true but I want to double check.

For a $\geq$ 0,b $\geq$ 0, c $\geq$ 0

Comment: What cases did you check?

Comment: I will edit my comment my question to show what cases I checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $c=-5$, $a=-1$, and $b=-2$.  Then $\min\{a+b,c\}=-5$, but $\min\{a,c\}+\min\{b,c\}=-10$.
Perhaps you are assuming that all numbers are non-negative?

The statement is true if $a,b,c$ are non-negative. I trust you've checked all the cases.

Comment: I am considering positive values only I should have edited my question to remark that.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that the numbers are positive. Sorry I should have mentioned that! I edited my question.